# MySQL Removing Value If Exists in Another Row

Tags: mysql, sql

Ok so I have a problem.

Ive got a Many to Many Relationship between Author & Book which creates a Junction table which I have named CoverPage.

```
 Author:
 AuthorID
 AuthorName

 CoverPage: (Junction Table)
 AuthorID
 BookID

 Book:
 BookID
 BookTitle
 BookType
```

Problem: Create statement that displays all Authors who have written a Fiction book but do not display any authors who have created a Historical book.

For Example:

```
AuthorName:     BookName:            Book Type:
John Smith     The Awakening       Fiction
John Smith     WW2                 Historical
Jack Johnson   The last Alien      Fiction
```

The query should only show Jack Johnson because John Smith even though he created a Fiction book he also created a Historical book but unfortunately in my queries he still appears.

Something like:

```
Select distinct AuthorName
From Author, Book, CoverPage
Where Author.AuthorID=CoverPage.AuthorID 
And Book.BookID=CoverPage.BookID 
And BookType = 'Fiction' And Not BookType = 'Historical';
```

Or

```
 SELECT distinct AuthorName, EmailAddress 
 FROM Author
 LEFT JOIN CoverPage ON Author.AuthorID = CoverPage.Author_AuthorID
 LEFT JOIN Book ON CoverPage.Book_BookID = Book.BookID
 Where Not BookType = 'Historical'
 Group By AuthorID;
```

Here are my tables:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Publisher` (
`PublisherID` VARCHAR(3) NOT NULL,
`PublisherName` VARCHAR(30) NULL,
`City` VARCHAR(15) NULL,
`ContactNumber` VARCHAR(10) NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`PublisherID`))
 ENGINE = InnoDB;

 CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Author` (
  `AuthorID` INT NOT NULL,
`AuthorName` VARCHAR(20) NULL,
`EmailAddress` VARCHAR(25) NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`AuthorID`))
 ENGINE = InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Book` (
`BookID` INT NOT NULL,
`BookTitle` VARCHAR(30) NULL,
`BookType` VARCHAR(10) NULL,
`Price` FLOAT NULL,
`PaperBack?` VARCHAR(5) NULL,
`Publisher_PublisherID` VARCHAR(3) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`BookID`),
INDEX `fk_Book_Publisher1_idx` (`Publisher_PublisherID` ASC),
CONSTRAINT `fk_Book_Publisher1`
FOREIGN KEY (`Publisher_PublisherID`)
REFERENCES `Publisher` (`PublisherID`)
ON DELETE NO ACTION
ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `CoverPage` (
`Book_BookID` INT NOT NULL,
`Author_AuthorID` INT NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`Book_BookID`, `Author_AuthorID`),
INDEX `fk_Book_has_Author_Author1_idx` (`Author_AuthorID` ASC),
INDEX `fk_Book_has_Author_Book1_idx` (`Book_BookID` ASC),
CONSTRAINT `fk_Book_has_Author_Book1`
FOREIGN KEY (`Book_BookID`)
REFERENCES `Book` (`BookID`)
ON DELETE NO ACTION
ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
CONSTRAINT `fk_Book_has_Author_Author1`
FOREIGN KEY (`Author_AuthorID`)
REFERENCES `Author` (`AuthorID`)
ON DELETE NO ACTION
ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;

insert into Publisher values ('P11','Eureka Publishing', 'Parramatta', '9981 3909' );
insert into Publisher values ('P12','Lishpub Book Publishing', 'Penrith', '9971 3000' );
insert into Publisher values ('P13','The Publisher Corp', 'Gosford', '9931 2999' );
insert into Publisher values ('P15','Stewart Publishing', 'Bankstown', '9931 7000' );
insert into Publisher values ('P14','George Street Publishing', 'Sydney CBD', '9981 4111' );
insert into Author values (321, 'Barry White', 'b.white@gmail.com');
insert into Author values (322, 'Bill Cosby', 'billc@hotmail.com');
insert into Author values (323, 'George Ryan', 'gryan@yahoo.com');
insert into Author values (324, 'Jon Snow', 'jsnow@yahoo.com');
insert into Book values (4321, 'The Awakening', 'Historical', '20.00', 'yes', 'P11');
insert into Book values (4322, 'Indianna Jones', 'Fiction', '30.00', 'yes', 'P12');
insert into Book values (4324, 'Star Wars', 'Fiction', '20.00', 'yes', 'P14');
insert into Book values (4323, 'The Lost Magic', 'Education', '10.00', 'no', 'P13');
insert into Book values (4325, 'World War', 'Historical', '20.00', 'yes', 'P14');
insert into Book values (4326, 'Doctor No', 'Fiction', '25.00', 'yes', 'P12');
insert into Book values (4327, 'Spiderman', 'Fiction', '10.00', 'no', 'P12');
insert into CoverPage values (4321, 321);
insert into CoverPage values (4321, 323);
insert into CoverPage values (4324, 322);
insert into CoverPage values (4325, 322);
insert into CoverPage values (4324, 323);
insert into CoverPage values (4326, 323);
insert into CoverPage values (4327, 323);
insert into CoverPage values (4327, 324);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by using `NOT IN` and getting a list of all authors that have written historical books and excluding them from your main query.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  a.AuthorName
FROM Author a
JOIN CoverPage cp on cp.author_AuthorID = a.AuthorID
JOIN Book b on cp.book_BookID = b.BookID
WHERE b.BookType = 'Fiction'
AND a.AuthorID NOT IN 
    (SELECT cp.author_AuthorID
    FROM CoverPage cp
    JOIN Book b ON cp.book_BookID = b.BookID
    WHERE BookType = 'Historical')
```

**[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7e460e/11/0)**

Comment: No values returned unfortunately :(

Comment: Ive updated my original post so you may see my table :)

Answer (score 1):

Consider the `NOT EXISTS` clause:

```
SELECT a.AuthorName
FROM Author a
INNER JOIN CoverPage c ON a.AuthorID = c.AuthorID 
INNER JOIN Book b ON b.BookID = c.BookID AND b.BookType = 'Fiction'

WHERE NOT EXISTS
 (SELECT 1 FROM Author sub_a 
  INNER JOIN CoverPage sub_c
     ON sub_a.AuthorID = sub_c.AuthorID 
  INNER JOIN Book sub_b
     ON sub_b.BookID = sub_c.BookID AND sub_b.BookType = 'Historical'
  WHERE sub_a.AuthorID = a.AuthorID);
```

Comment: Tried this but no values appeared, but I triple checked by value inserts something definitely should appear

Comment: Please set up a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952/1422451) with data and use [rextester](http://rextester.com/) or [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/), selecting *MySQL* language in either. Use `SHOW CREATE TABLE` from your workbench/console.

Comment: Okay so ive created my Schema and yeah, still has no results. How do I show you my tables? sorry im a noob :(

Comment: You had to adjust column names as your post does not match actual. See [rextester](http://rextester.com/GAKQ71456) of this solution returning only *Jon Snow*. Also for some reason *Books* was failing on the demo, so I named as *BookTbl* (adjust to actual).